# make variable from sheet tabs and one template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

```
function createDocs() {
  var headers = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1wjmfG-mTYFw_JQZIondppy-VxffdV3fFzcEi8Og', 'Juli 2021!A5:K5');
  var tactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1wjmfG-mTYFw_JQZIondppy-VoCguU_VgVfdsdcEi8Og', 'Juli 2021!H6:K4000');
  var templateId = '1B2IzVd03MmoPtT7Tcvce8I9wXGrb6fYXCnz8JikAs';

 
    for(var i = 0; i < tactics.values.length; i++){
    
    var textId = tactics.values[i][0];
    
    var titel = tactics.values[i][1];
      
    var words = tactics.values[i][3];
    
    //Make a copy of the template file
    var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();
    
    //Rename the copied file
    DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('NEW ' + textId +' '+ titel + ' ' + words);
    
    //Get the document body as a variable
    var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
    
    
    //Insert the textid name
    body.replaceText('##textID##', textId)
    
    //Insert the titel name
    body.replaceText('##subject##', titel)
    
    //Insert the words name
    body.replaceText('##words##', words)
        
    //Append tactics
    parseTactics(headers.values[0], tactics.values[i], body);
    
  }

}

function parseTactics(headers, tactics, body){ 
  
  for(var i = 1; i < tactics.length; i++){
    {tactics[i] != '' && 
      body.appendListItem(headers[i] + ' | ' + tactics[i] + ' net').setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
    }
    
  }
}
```

So I have this code that works fine on specific tabs and creating docs based on template.

How can i make it so I the code works for all tabs?

All tabs of interest have the format: "month year".
There are some tabs not of interest that have different format.
All tabs have there own corresponding folders.

Goal is to just have a template file I can copy the each folder that needs docs created.

Comment: Try selecting with regular expressions

Comment: thanks, any good tutorial you recommend? just winging it here man :)

Comment: Hey man were all winging it.  Try googling regular expressions

Comment: yea , goosh why didn't I thinḱ of that :) yea I did ĺots of options,, but sure thank you kindly

Answer (score 2):

If your sheet/tabs are something like this: `November 2021`

Then you could use something like this to filter them from the rest of your sheets:

```
function selectSheets() {
  const mA = [...Array.from(new Array(12).keys(), x => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(2021, x), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMMM"))];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => {
    let t = sh.getName().split(' ');
    if (~mA.indexOf(t[0]) && t[1].match(/\d{4}/)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }).map(sh => sh.getName());
  Logger.log(shts.join(','))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! will try